# Удалить элементы HashMap, используя элементы ArrayList

Tags: java, коллекции, arraylist, hashmap

У меня есть кеш вида Map<String, Model> map. Ключ id объекта Model. Model имеет поля id, name, type.
Элементы которые нужно удалить хранятся в кеше, мне нужно удалить все элементы, которые не равны элементам в List по model.getId()

```
for(Iterator<String> iterator = map.keySet().iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
        String next = iterator.next();
        String key = map.get(next).getId();
        if (list.stream()
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .noneMatch(Model -> Model.getId().equals(key))) {
            iterator.remove();
        }
    }
```

В тестах функционал описанный выше работает, но на деле такой механизм работает не корректно, удаляет все данные которые находит.
Помогите решить проблему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(); //Содержит ключи мапы которые нужно оставить
Map<String, Model> map= new HashMap();
        for(Iterator<String> iterator = map.keySet().iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
            String id = iterator.next();
            if (!list.contains(id)) {               
                iterator.remove(); //Удаляет все map кроме ключей листа
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, то необходимо сделать следующее:

```
list.stream().map(Model::getId).forEach(map::remove);
```